# What is System Data Storage

Tags: ipad, storage, ipados

I've checked my iPad storage and I see the System Data storage is taking up too much space. I know it contains any needed system data and caches. How do I delete these caches in system data storage?[image: Current iPad System Data Storage (8,82 GB)]

iPad Air 2

iPadOS 15.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System storage contains core system files that are necessary for your iPhone to function and also some temporary cache files. There isn't any easy way to delete these cache files. You can try deleting your Safari history & website data and restarting your phone to clean some of the cache files. Occasionally (I do it once a year), I make a backup of iPhone data and reset it. This might take some time to do but certainly deletes a lot of the cache files and make your phone storage as it would be out of box.